# Professional titles for IT Engineers

Tags: business-japanese

I'm trying to figure out what title would be appropriate for my business card at work. At my previous company, I was given ヘッドフロントエンドエンジニア, which is a little lengthy. I'd like a way to include seniority (Senior Frontend Engineer) without tacking on more katakana if there's an appropriate way to do so.

Comment: This is well beyond the scope of this question and I assume you know this if you work(ed) for a Japanese company, but just in case: it's also worth noting that the delineation of technical roles and titles associated with them are different at many tech companies in Japan. Many international/modern companies will have "software engineers" as the west knows them, but there are still a good number of companies that have "system engineers" (architect) and "programmers" (code monkey) split instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your official title, so if you have a boss, you should ask them. If you can decide your official title yourself, please read on.

フロントエンドエンジニア may seem long, but it cannot be shortened. フロントエンド is a fairly new concept, and it cannot be written in kanji. エンジニア would sound much nicer than something like 開発者.

ヘッド is already short enough. シニア and チーフ have similar meanings, but they're not shorter. You can use 主任 or 首席 if you really like, but IMHO the katakana-only expression would look nicer. (Just to be sure, there can be only one ヘッド/チーフ/主任/首席, but there can be many シニア's in your team.)

Comment: Thanks. It was left up to me to decide, so I went with シニアエンジニア. I appreciate it.